Firebase create multiple cloud functions
I have created a cloud function in index.js. But I want to create a different function in the same app. Can I create a different file or folder and name it differently, say...(functions.js) to create the new function or do I have to create all my functions in the same file index.js?

All of the functions in a project must be exported from the index.js entrypoint.  However, the actual code that implement's the function's logica can live anywhere else in the project.  Typically, with JavaScript, this involves using import or require to load the code from another file so that you can call it from the place where the exported function is defined.  There are any number of ways to organize your code in multiple files, so it's up to you to pick one and implement it.  The documentation discusses some options, so you should start by reviewing that.
